# javascript set new data value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 input boxes.

When I input a value into the first one, the javascript function `checkMyKad()` is triggered.

`checkMyKad()` gets value in first input box, edits it, and alerts new value.

I want new to be set into second input box. How do I get new value to be shown in 2nd input box?

```
 <div class="form-group" style="color:#0000FF; margin-left:160px;" >
    <input type="text" placeholder="Please input value" id="myKadC" maxlength="4" size="10" onchange="checkMyKad()" required>
    <input type="text" id="newVal" maxlength="20" size="20"/>
</div>
```

javascript function

```
function checkMyKad() {
    var mykadC = $('#myKadC').val();
    var newVal='Value is :   '+'-'+mykadC;
    alert(newVal);
    $('#newValId').val(newVal);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to target the wrong id, it should be `$('#newVal')`

```js
function checkMyKad() {
    var mykadC = $('#myKadC').val();
    var newVal='Value is :   '+'-'+mykadC;
    alert(newVal);
    $('#newVal').val(newVal);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" style="color:#0000FF; margin-left:160px;" >
    <input type="text" placeholder="Please input value" id="myKadC" maxlength="4" size="10" onchange="checkMyKad()" required>
    <input type="text" id="newVal" maxlength="20" size="20"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `$('#newValId')` instead of `$('#newVal')`

Answer (score 0):

target id is wrong.

`$('#newValId').val(newVal);` -> `$('#newVal').val(newVal);`

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would do something like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" >
    <h3>Pure JavaScript</h3>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Please input value"  maxlength="4" size="10" onchange="checkMyKad(this)" required>
    <input type="text" maxlength="20" size="20"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group" >
    <h3>Using jQuery</h3>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Please input value"  maxlength="4" size="10" onchange="checkMyKadJQuery(this)" required>
    <input type="text" maxlength="20" size="20"/>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function checkMyKad(element) {
    let oldValue = element.value;
    let newValue = 'Value is : -'+oldValue;
    alert(newValue);
    element.nextElementSibling.value = newValue;
}

function checkMyKadJQuery(element) {
    let oldValue = $(element).val();
    let newValue = 'Value is : -'+oldValue;
    alert(newValue);
    $(element).next().val(newValue);
}
</script>
```

Doing it like that would allow the functions to be reused.